# Work with null value in Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have some function with lambda which is returning some object or null

```
public Function<SomeObject1, SomeObject2> lambdaFunc = obj1 -> {
    // here I do some logic, convert obj1 to obj2 and on the end return obj2 or null
};
```

I am using that function in my stream like that:

```
someObj0.setObjects2(entity.getObjects1().stream().map(lambdaFunc).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Here when `lambdaFunc` return null I got exception, I think it is due collect function. Is some pretty solution to do that? I will be ok if that stream return also null when `lambdaFunc` return null, and don't continue.

**EDIT 1:**
Ok I tried `filter(Objects::nonNull)` function but I find out problem is with `entity.getObjects1()` so I need prevent call stream function if it return null, any ideas?

Comment: So add a null check before calling .stream on entity.getObjects1()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sinply add filtering for nonNull values:

```
someObj0.setObjects2(
 Optional.ofNullable(entity.getObjects1())
.orElse(Coollections.emptyList()) // return original Object or singleton empty from Collections 
.stream()
.map(lambdaFunc)
.filter(Objects::nonNull) // add checking here
.collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Here you have two choices:

- First would be to wrap getObjects1() in a Optional
- Second would be more clean - never return null, initialize your object with empty collection at start. **Methods that return collections should never return null**, but an emptyCollection from Collections util class. So that you would not have to worry about the nulls.

so

```
class SomeObj0 {
private List<SomeObject1> col =Collections.emptyList();

// getters/setters

}
```

I assume your collections is a list, but you can prevent it with a Optional:)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer I tried it and I find out exception is due stream function, check EDIT 1 please.

Comment: Just use Optional:) Example above

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the case where you should use `Optional` instead of `null`. 
You don't have much details about what `entity.getObjects1()` is doing, but one thing is for sure, if you avoid returning `null` all along it will save you a `NullPointerException` further on.

You can try something like this which is clearer as to the intent you are doing:

```
Optional.ofNullable(entity.getObjects1())
        .map(objects -> objects.stream()           
                               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                               .map(lambdaFunc)
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet()))
        .ifPresent(someObj0::setObjects2)
```

If you change `entity.getObjects1()` to return `Optional` you avoid the first call to `ofNullable()`.

I would also encapsulate the `objects.stream()` part to another method that takes the collection and lambda function and returns another collection, to make the code a bit clearer.